# Visual Studio Code | ETag does not represent the latest state of the file "application.py". Download the file from Azure to get the latest version

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-application-insights

I'm getting this error from Azure App Service extension in Visual Studio code

```
ETag does not represent the latest state of the file "application.py". Download the file from Azure to get the latest version.
```

May I know what is this error means?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error while updating a file in running web app? The file in the deployed app service might have been updated from a different source (either by someone else or CI/CD pipeline) between the time you downloaded and the time you are trying to update after editing.

Comment: Yes, when the app is running locally I want it to be updated on the Azure as well.